# How to open files in a certain range from the command prompt in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, command-line

I want use the Windows 10 Command Prompt to open files whose names are in certain range.
The files i want to open have names like `AF87314.corr.fits` (some files may have .corr.fits.discarded extension) and as an example suppose i want to open the files from `AF87314` to `AF87320`. On Linux (Ubuntu) i can use

```
ds9 AF873{14..20}.corr.fits
```

(ds9 is the program that i use to open those images). On Windows i cannot.
Is there a solution to my problem?

Thanks in advance to all of you.

EDIT: Thanks Ian C. for giving a possible solution, but it is not the one i am looking for since each image opens in a new window of the program. I need to pass all of the filenames to the command at once, so that only one window is open at a time and i can work on all of the images at the same time.

EDIT2: Thanks LPChip as well, but something doen not work doing what you suggested. Using for instance `ds9 AF873{30..35}.corr.fits` the program gives an error saying that the file `[full-path-to-file]/AF873` could not be opened (please note that the latter part of the filename is missing). I'm in the right folder however, i can open any files with `ds9 AF87330.corr.fits`.

EDIT3: I think i found a possible solution, which is to use `findstr`. Later, when i get home i'll test it a bit more, because it uses regex and i'm not familiar with it.

Comment: Command Prompt can't do this, but Powershell does.

Comment: That could be okay, but how?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, similar to how it is done in Linux. So `.\ds9 AF873{14..20}.corr.fits`

Comment: Please see the edit.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how the syntax is, that's why I added: If I'm not mistaken...

Comment: That's ok, but how can i get to the right syntax?

Comment: Googling for `powershell loops numbers` for example, which brings me to: http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/powershell/powershell_loops.htm

Comment: Ok, please see EDIT

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [FOR loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_l.html).

```
FOR /l %K in (14,1,20) DO DS9.EXE AF873%K.corr.fits
```

Things to note

- The %K is your variable number that changes with each file.
- Because /l is a counter, this only works with numbers, not with other characters
- For simplicity sake, I am leaving out any reference to file paths.
- /l does not use leading zeroes. If we take your example and wanted to start at 08 instead of 14

  - You can't use `in (8,1,20)`, the result would be `AF8738`, `AF8739`, `AF87310`, `AF87311`, `...`
  - You would have to use `in (308,1,20) ... AF87%K.corr.fits`

Comment: This is what i was looking for since the part of the filename that changes is just made of numbers.

Comment: I tried and I was wrong, this is not what i was looking for. It opens N times the program where N is the number of files i want to open. If possible i'd like all the files to be passed as arguments to the program once for all.

Comment: Not all programs support multi-document windows. See Notepad and MS Paint. Others like Notepad++, Adobe Reader & Excel do. I believe you can specify multiple documents on the command line to open them simultaneously; e.g. `Excel.exe doc1 doc2 doc3`, but I don't remember ever seeing a command line dynamically expanded to open multiple documents in one window.

Comment: ds9 does support opening multiple files in the same window, but i need to open more than 10 files at the same time, writing each filename each time is a pain...